# BigQuery: Join based on closest timestamp

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am joining two tables based on closest timestamp in BigQuery and getting this error. Unsupported subquery with table in join predicate.

```
SELECT gs.user_session_id
      ,dtc._date
      ,dtc.hit_timestamp _timestamp
      ,dtc.user_id
FROM  ga.2_deduped_twice_click_data dtc LEFT JOIN ga.sessions gs ON dtc.user_id = gs.user_id 
and dtc.hit_timestamp = ( SELECT dtc2.hit_timestamp FROM ga.2_deduped_twice_click_data dtc2 order by ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dtc.hit_timestamp, gs._timestamp, MILLISECOND)) LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dtc.user_id, dtc._date ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(dtc._timestamp, gs._timestamp, SECOND))) AS row_num. -- in next stage filter where row_num=1

Answer (score 2):

You could try a mix of `ARRAY_AGG` and `ORDER BY diff LIMIT 1`:

```
WITH a AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    [STRUCT(TIMESTAMP('2018-01-02 20:01:00') AS time, 'monkey' AS animal)
     ,STRUCT('2018-03-04 10:10:10', 'lion')
     ,STRUCT('2018-07-04 10:10:10', 'donkey')
    ]) 
),
b AS  (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    [STRUCT(TIMESTAMP('2017-01-02 10:01:00') AS time, 'one' AS festival)
     ,STRUCT('2019-03-04 10:10:10', 'two')
     ,STRUCT('2018-07-04 10:10:10', 'three')
     ,STRUCT('2018-03-05 10:10:10', 'four')
    ]) 
)


SELECT b,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * 
   FROM a 
   ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b.time, a.time, SECOND))
   LIMIT 1) closest
FROM b
```

[image]

Comment: This looked like exactly what I needed, but BQ told me "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN. " even after adding a where clause to limit only to rows which have matching date:

```
select event, (
  select as struct *
  from master.telemetry as telemetry
  where EXTRACT(DATE FROM event.time) = EXTRACT(DATE FROM telemetry.time)
  order by ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event.time, telemetry.time, SECOND))
  limit 1
) as telemetry
from master.event as event
limit 10
```

Comment: please post a new question with a working example we can use to solve this problem

Comment: thanks, I just posted a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59380153/bigquery-join-all-columns-of-a-row-nearest-to-the-time-of-current-row-from-a-di