# BigQuery: join all columns of a row nearest to the time of current row from a different table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery database with fairly long tables holding IoT events and telemetry data, where I need to find the telemetry data point closest in time to each event.

Due to (as I understand performance related) limitations in BigQuery subqueries, I haven't managed to get results back so far.

I have found another similar question ([BigQuery: Join based on closest timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170852/bigquery-join-based-on-closest-timestamp/)) which has a promising answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58172418/21217) but adapting it to my tables I got the error message `Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.` even after I tried to limit the telemetry query with some where clauses.

My query currently looks like this:

```
select event, (
  select as struct *
  from master.telemetry as telemetry
  where EXTRACT(DATE FROM event.time) = EXTRACT(DATE FROM telemetry.time) and event.module_id = telemetry.module_id
  order by ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event.time, telemetry.time, SECOND))
  limit 1
) as closest_telemetry
from master.event as event
```

Not really sure what else to try for this particular use case. I was just wondering if introducing [time based partitioning](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions) to the telemetry table would help?

Edit: sample data JSON

event:

```
{
  "id": "33373",
  "module_id": "module-standard-7",
  "time": "2019-11-05 15:09:31.650209 UTC",
  "state": "fault"
},
```

telemetry:

```
{
  "module_id": "module-standard-7",
  "latitude": "50.721649169921875",
  "longitude": "-1.8665790557861328",
  "time": "2019-12-07 16:37:35.721218 UTC",
  ... (many other columns which are not relevant in this case)
},
```

desired output (telemetry merged into event):

```
{
  "id": "33373",
  "module_id": "module-standard-7",
  "time": "2019-11-05 15:09:31.650209 UTC",
  "state": "fault"
  "telemetry.latitude": "50.721649169921875",
  "telemetry.longitude": "-1.8665790557861328",
  "telemetry.time": "2019-12-07 16:37:35.721218 UTC",
},
```

It would be even better if the telemetry fields were unnested, but would like to keep its time as a separate column to know how far they were.

Comment: Can you put sample data and desired results *in the question* as text tables?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GordonLinoff, I added them, though formatted as JSON as that's what was easy to copy from the BQ output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative answer - in this case I created the physical tables to make sure this runs when tables are not ephemeral out of a `WITH` statement:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp.a AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    [STRUCT(TIMESTAMP('2018-01-02 20:01:00') AS time, 'monkey' AS animal)
     ,STRUCT('2018-03-04 10:10:10', 'lion')
     ,STRUCT('2018-07-04 10:10:10', 'donkey')
    ]) 
)
;
CREATE TABLE temp.b AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    [STRUCT(TIMESTAMP('2017-01-02 10:01:00') AS time, 'one' AS festival)
     ,STRUCT('2019-03-04 10:10:10', 'two')
     ,STRUCT('2018-07-04 10:10:10', 'three')
     ,STRUCT('2018-03-05 10:10:10', 'four')
    ]) 
)
;


SELECT b.*,
  ARRAY_AGG(a 
   ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b.time, a.time, SECOND))
   LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] closest
FROM temp.b
JOIN temp.a 
ON ABS(timestamp_diff(b.time,a.time, DAY)) < 360*2
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

The clause `ON ABS(timestamp_diff(b.time,a.time, DAY)) < 360*2` is a sanity check to avoid explosive joins. Bring `360*2` to a way lower limit if your data is more dense than the presented here.

[image]

Comment: Maybe consider `SAFE_OFFSET` in the event there isn't a close option.

Answer (score 0):

Yay, this query based on [Felipe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381370/21217) worked:

```
SELECT event.*,
  ARRAY_AGG(telemetry 
   ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(event.time, telemetry.time, SECOND))
   LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] as closest_telemetry
FROM master.event
JOIN master.telemetry
ON EXTRACT(DATE FROM event.time) = EXTRACT(DATE FROM telemetry.time) and event.module_id = telemetry.module_id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4
```

That said, it took 42.4 sec and used 22 min 34.991 sec slot time

I guess the fact that both tables have many rows resulted in a huge join even with the date limitation put in place. I tried to limit the join condition to 1 hour instead of the same day, but the results were slightly worse, I think the problem there is having to run the evaluation itself on every row combination.

[image: horrific stats]

Comment: if I had a larger dataset, I would investigate a way to make `ON EXTRACT(DATE FROM event.time) = EXTRACT(DATE FROM telemetry.time) ` more efficient -- seems like an interesting new question :)